# How to structure PHP AJAX functions within a web application?

Tags: php, ajax

I work for a small company (read: three employees) that develops web applications, and we've been consistently using this structure for each page of our apps:

- PHP page 'placeholder' that sets up the environment.
- HTML seperated into a Smarty .tpl file.
- JavaScript separated into a different .js file.
- And a 'ajax_functions.php' file to be posted to by the JavaScript.

I feel pretty good about the file structure, although it is a bit messy (and if I'm wrong, please let me know!). My question is specifically about that 'ajax_functions.php' page. Right now the JavaScript will make a $.post request to something along the lines of 'ajax_functions.php?action=subscribe', and the page itself looks like this:

```
    switch($_GET['action']){
      case('subscribe'):
        //Do stuff...
      break;
      default:
        die('Invalid request');
    }
```

I just feel this way is too insecure: if someone wants to link directly to the page and repeatedly spam it with info, there's little way to stop them. Is there perhaps a better to structure the requests?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, you can still lock this down with session management, or you could generate single use request tokens that are generated on the first page, passed through the the ajax request, and validated in your ajax_functions.php script

Comment: Take a look at this previous question regarding securing AJAX requests - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953954/detecting-ajax-in-php-and-making-sure-request-was-from-my-own-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  seems pretty good.

For contrast heres what I do (pretty similar)

My structure

-A JS file for the AJAX etc

-A PHP classe / functions that process the _POST and _GET data

Thats it really.

The class / functions check for the correct _POST or _GET data and do any other validation checks I need.

From the functions I return a array, which can then be json_encoded and sent back to the JS

This works well for me because the functions can be used for forms that send the same data.