# How to verify JQuery/AJAX referer to prevent CSRF?

Tags: php, jquery, http, csrf, referer

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "????")
```

What would the `HTTP_REFERER` be if this page was reached by a JQuery $.post request?

Comment: If you are doing this for security purposes, please don't. The referer header can be easily spoofed by the client.

Comment: @phpdev "Actually yes, according to the OWASP CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet in most cases checking the referer is enough to patch a CSRF vulnerability."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

Note That not all servers provide this variable

and you can read this 
[Detecting Ajax in PHP and making sure request was from my own website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953954/detecting-ajax-in-php-and-making-sure-request-was-from-my-own-website)

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for THANK YOU